# Looking for a series of books, collection of short horror stories from the 70s or 80s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It was a series of books, each with a collection of stories.  I used to check these out at the library one at a time and scare myself silly:

One story was of a young man who kept seeing an older ghost staring at him through his window.  The old ghost appear each night, would say "old wine in new bottles," then disappear.  Then one night the young man finds himself staring through the window at his own body now inhabited by the old ghost.

Another story was of an antique chest bought for cheap.  The buyer brings it home and is haunted each night by a hand coming out and beckoning him closer.  He dismisses the visions as nightmares.  He eventually disappears and when his possessions are hauled out of the now renterless apartment, the movers notice the chest is heavy but locked.  They haul the chest back to the antique shop.

Another story was of a young girl who sees a gardening ghost regularly at her house.  She is not frightened, develops a crush on the man and attempts to make contact.  It turns out she is the ghost and causes his death as he is startled during a car ride.  Unfortunately she now sees the man in his "death state" mutilated and burnt (He saw her the same way - thus the accident).  They will be together this way for eternity.

There was always a vampire detective story at the end to lighten the mood of the reader.  The vampire was a "humanitarian" dedicated to chasing and eradicating the homicidal maniacs of his species.

I've been looking for many years for any clues to identifying this series of short stories.  It was an edited collection and in "young adult" fiction.

Comment: Were the stories by various authors, or were they all by the same author? Were they hardcover books? American, British, Australian?

Comment: Various authors, edited by a well known horror fiction writer. I think I've found the books in the "Index of the Supernatural."  I must have mashed up "Ghosts and Ghoulies" short stories with "Shadows" series 1-10.  The later anthology is listed in Wiki but only the titles of the stories, not the content.  Going to have to try and find "Shadows" books in the library.  "The Calamander Chest" and "Old Wine in New Bottles" is in "Ghosts and Ghoulies."

Comment: The 3rd story you describe, about the girl who sees the gardening ghost sounds very much like an episode of "Night Visions"(2001 TV series), called 'My So-Called Life and Death'. I wonder if the writer of this episode 'borrowed' it from this collection with some minor changes?

Comment: Always a candidate for these sorts of questions: the "Scary Stories to Tell in The Dark" series - but since you didn't additionally mention creepy illustrations that may rule those out :)